# Supervisord with django writing separate logs for each program

Tags: django, supervisord, django-supervisor

I'm using supervisord (through [django-supervisor](https://github.com/rfk/django-supervisor) a thin wrapper around supervisor) to run multiple processes with my Django installation. 
My problem is all the logs are written to the `supervisord` log file (in this example out.log) instead of the different log files.

the conf file (cleaned up):

```
[supervisord]
logfile=/var/log/server/ourserver/out.log


[rpcinterface:supervisor]
supervisor.rpcinterface_factory = supervisor.rpcinterface:make_main_rpcinterface

[supervisorctl]
serverurl=unix:///var/run/supervisor.sock ; use a unix:// URL  for a unix socket


[program:webserver]
command=uwsgi uwsgi.ini
stout_logfile = /var/log/server/ourserver/django.log
redirect_stderr = true
;autostart = true
;autorestart = true

[program:celery]
command=celery worker -B -A server.celery --loglevel=info --concurrency=4
;autostart = true
;autorestart = true
stout_logfile = /var/logs/server/ourserver/celery.log
redirect_stderr = true

[program:updater]
command=python -u updater.py
;directory=/home/ubuntu/server/ourserver
;autostart = true
;autorestart = true
stout_logfile = /var/logs/server/ourserver/updater.log
redirect_stderr = true
```

Comment: Unless its a typing mistake `stout_logfile` should be `stdout_logfile`

Answer (score 2):

replace **stout_logfile** with **stdout_logfile**